# web scraping python list index out of range

Tags: python, web-scraping, indexing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to use python to web scrape some ranking list of kworb.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
df = pd.read_html('https://kworb.net/spotify/country/hk_weekly.html', attrs={'id':'spotifyweekly'})[0]
df[['Artist','Song']]=df['Artist and Title'].str.split(' - ', n=1, expand=True)
df[['Pos','Artist','Song']].to_excel('yourfile.xlsx', index = False)

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://kworb.net/spotify/country/hk_weekly.html").content, 'html.parser')

data = []

for e in soup.select('#spotifyweekly tr:has(td)'):
    c = list(e.stripped_strings)
    data .append({
        'Pos':c[0],
        'Artist':c[2],
        'Song':c[4]
    })

pd.DataFrame(data).to_excel('yourfile.xlsx', index = False)
```

and it comes out an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lohub\OneDrive\desktop\scrape.py", line 17, in <module>
    'Song':c[4]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: The list `c` has too few elements.  `c[4]` does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

*Be aware - There is only one option needed `pandas` or `BeuatifulSoup` from your code, while first one will deliver a propper result.*

---

As mentioned earlier, there are not enough items to select by index, which is probably caused by the specific row differing in number of values from the rest:

```
<tr><td>61</td>
<td></td>
<td class="text mp"><div><a href="../artist/1IDuSpntFl2Mutofvrrutc.html">Jason Chan</a> - <a href="../track/1eId3TVzGrwv73YAWAVQMX.html">你瞞我瞞</a></div></td>
<td></td>
<td></td><td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td></tr>
```

That will result in the following if you print `c`, so last index would be 3:

```
['61', 'Jason Chan', '-', '你瞞我瞞']
```

An alternative that handels this issue would be:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get("https://kworb.net/spotify/country/hk_weekly.html").content, 'html.parser')

data = []

for e in soup.select('#spotifyweekly tr:has(td)'):
    data .append({
        'Pos':e.td.text,
        'Artist':e.a.text,
        'Song':e.a.find_next_sibling('a').text
    })
pd.DataFrame(data).to_excel('yourfile.xlsx', index = False)
```